# How to set session cookie_domain when using Zend\Session

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my code, I've followed the basic example from Zend\Session documentation:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig;

$config = new StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions(array(
    //'remember_me_seconds' => 1800,
    //'name'                => 'zf2',
    'cookie_domain' => '.jt.martyndev',
));
$manager = new SessionManager($config);
Container::setDefaultManager($manager);

$container = new Container('namespace');
$container->item = 'foo';

?>
<pre><?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?></pre>
```

I can see my data written to session but the PHPSESSID in the firebug shows that the cookie still contains the full domain (with subdomain - dom1.jt.martyndev, instead of .jt.martyndev)

Answer (score 1):

OK, would seem that Zend's documentation is a little misleading? http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.config.html Listed under StandardConfig it has "name", "cookie_domain". However, the implementation within this class that should set the INI is:

```
/**
* Set storage option in backend configuration store
*
* Does nothing in this implementation; others might use it to set things
* such as INI settings.
*
* @param  string $storageName
* @param  mixed $storageValue
* @return StandardConfig
*/
public function setStorageOption($storageName, $storageValue)
{
   return $this;
}

/**
* Retrieve a storage option from a backend configuration store
*
* Used to retrieve default values from a backend configuration store.
*
* @param  string $storageOption
* @return mixed
*/
public function getStorageOption($storageOption)
{
   return;
}
```

Instead, I changed my code to SessionConfig and I can see in the inspector that the cookie domain is set as I wanted it:

```
use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig;
$config = new SessionConfig();
.
.
```

Comment: Agree that the docs are a bit confusing - `StandardConfig` is the base class and holds config when you *aren't* using the standard PHP sessions (but you are). `SessionConfig` extends it and calls the correct ini_set functions.